# Problems with notifications aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, aquaris

I have this problem. Do not get notifications from Facebook, twitter, gmail and Dekko or the application. Also in the application telegram slow to receive notifications and if I'm inside the app and lock the device did not get any. No sound, just vibrating.

Note: Notifications are enabled and I throw attempts with both Wi-Fi and mobile data and the result is the same.

If I could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: as far as I know, Dekko is not able to display notifications yet. See the [app description](https://uappexplorer.com/app/dekko.dekkoproject) for details

Comment: Still, the rest of the notifications do not work, you know I can do?

Comment: You can have a look at [this bug list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers) and file a bug report, if there is none